# Capybara cannot detect element even though it is visible on page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I am using Capybara to manually fill out a page, however I am running into an issue.

When it tries to execute this line (I tried also setting visible to false):

```
find(:css, "[value='Laundry In Building']", visible: true).set(true)
```

It gets the following error:

```
Unable to find css "[value='Laundry In Building']"
```

This is confusing because I see the field in the browser when the test is running. Furthermore, when I output `page.body`, I get the following:

```
<div class="listing-edit-cb-item">
  <input class="cb" id="building_features_3" name="features[]"value="Laundry In Building" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="building_features_3">
    <span class="cb"></span>
    <span style="width: 200px; display: inline-block; font-size: 0.90em;">Laundry In Building</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

***Why is Capybara no table to detect the checkbox element?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the css applied to the checkbox, but I'll bet that it's not actually the checkbox you're seeing on the page.  Use your browsers dev console to take a look at whats actually shown on the page, it's probably using pseudo elements on the `span.cb` to replace the checkbox with images so they look the same across multiple browsers.  If you're using a recent release of Capybara you can do

```
check('Laundry In Building', allow_label_click: true)  # found by labels text
```

or

```
check(option: 'Laundry In Building', allow_label_click: true) # found by checkbox inputs value property
```

which will check the box by clicking on the visible label rather than the actual input that is hidden.  If using an older version you'd need to find the label instead and call click on it. Something like

```
find(:css, 'label', text: 'Laundry In Building').click
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I am currently click on the label like you suggested but didn't understand why my initial solution didn't work. Awesome.

Comment: @Huy Your initial solution didn't work because the checkbox input element isn't actually visible on the page, so you can't interact with it directly (even if you can find the element using `visible: false`, etc - Capybara still generally won't let you interact with the element because a user couldn't).  There is probably an image added to the span.cb (which is inside the label so clicking on it will toggle the checkbox too) to simulate the checkbox and make it look the same in multiple browsers.